# JIRA custom plugin params

Tags: java, virtual-machine, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I have a JIRA plugin, that was extended with some features. Right now I have to get outside of `velocity` template (`vm` file) a field name value.

I'd like to set that value as a param in `atlassian-plugin.xml` or some other file.

Where should I set that param and how can I access it from `vm` template ?

Answer (score 1):

you can easily take data on vm page by putting it in velocityParams like
velocityParams.put("dates", dates);
        velocityParams.put("projectCategory", projectCategory);
and on vm page you just write $variable name you want to get.
you will get it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best example of adding a parameter in atlassian-plugin.xml is the standard user picker and multi user picker fields. Their definition adds a parameter named "multiple" in the system-customfieldtypes-plugin.xml and they share code that changes according to how the parameter is set.

~Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at these helpful articles:

[Can I add configuration parameters to my atlassian-plugin.xml file?](http://docs.servicerocket.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1801)

[Storing plugin settings](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Storing+plugin+settings)

[Configuring the Plugin Descriptor - Adding Configuration Pages](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Configuring+the+Plugin+Descriptor#ConfiguringthePluginDescriptor-AddingConfigurationPages)